# MySQL not recognising datetime index in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, indexing

What I'm trying to do is index the first name of a person and the date they were born.

The table is laid out like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 fname VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 sname VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 age INT NOT NULL,
 born DATETIME NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY(id),
 INDEX name_age(fname, sname, age),
 INDEX name_date(fname, born)
)
```

However the index isn't recognised in a where statement like so:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * 
    -> FROM  `test` 
    -> WHERE fname =  "coby"
    -> AND born
    -> BETWEEN  "1900-05-02 06:23:00"
    -> AND  "2100-05-02 06:23:00";
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys      | key      | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | ref  | name_age,name_date | name_age | 12      | const |   45 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However it is recognised in an order by statement:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * 
    -> FROM  `test` 
    -> WHERE fname =  "coby"
    -> ORDER BY born;
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys      | key       | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | ref  | name_age,name_date | name_date | 12      | const |   45 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How do I make it so that the index is recognised in a where statement?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought, but why would it use the index when your date range is so large as to probably include the whole table?

Comment: MySQL is free to use or ignore indexes as it sees fit. In some cases it's simply more efficient to ignore the index and do a table scan, especially if the number of records is small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index **is** recognized, as seen in the column `possible_keys` of the result of the first `EXPLAIN` statement. It just happens, that for 45 rows the other index produces an equal or better query plan: The selectivity of your date range is close to zero.

The `ORDER BY` is another pair of shoes: As you use the index not only for selection, but also for ordering, it now becomes useful.